# Excel is not calculating formulas

Tags: excel

I have an Excel template where the underlying values are updated via SAS. There are predefined formulas in the template that do not update when the data changes.

The workbook is set to automatic calculation. F9, or any combination of keys and F9, does not update the cells. The only way to update them is to click inside the formula box and hit enter. The cells are not formatted as text.

These are simple formulas such as

```
=Data!A1
```

There are no error messages. The cell displayed values simply do not update.

Answer (score 1):

After that data has been refreshed touch:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

This is equivalent to issuing the VBA command:

```
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

Comment: This unfortunately is having no effect. No combination of keys+F9 is refreshing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, some cells/formulas in my workbook didn't calculate, while others did. Unfortunately, I never found the root cause.

What worked for me was to force calculation by setting the [forced calculation mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.forcefullcalculation).

This has a big disadvantage that it slows down the workbook significantly. Therefore I also re-set it again inside the macro that runs the workbook:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ForceFullCalculation = True
Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.ForceFullCalculation = False
```

It's an ugly workaround, but it's the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, Number format `Text` was selected in Home Tab of Excel, changing it to `General` solved the issue.[image]